# C2065 - Undecleared Identifier

Tags: c++

This is a program that is use to calculate the cost of  a garden and work out the price of the total garden, it then needs to be able to save the quotation to a file, so far I have got it working on the console, but I am unable to get it to save the file. This must be an easy fix, but I am just not sure what to do, I have only started learning c++ in the last week.

My code would not paste here without being in correctly formatted so I have put it on pastebin, sorry for the inconvenience. http://pastebin.com/YVpD00Jm

Comment: Errors from the compiler will tell you the line, and in this case, the NAME of the identified that's undeclared. Without that...?

Comment: You have to do some extra formatting effort when pasting code here: 1. Indent at least 4 blanks for each line 2. Replace all indentation TAB characters with a number of blanks. Putting the code on pastebin and just link there is not acceptable for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        if (quotation == "yes")
        // open a file in write mode.
   ofstream outfile;
```

You need braces around the `if` block

```
if (quotation == "yes")
{
    // open a file in write mode.
    ofstream outfile;
 ...
}
```